# how to get values in other class?

Tags: java, swing

I have JFrame named "Login" and another JPanel  "AddItemJpanel".
So i want to use user login name to AddItemJpanel.
here's how i tried bt it dosnt pass any values.

```
public class login{

public String getUserName() {
        String n=txtUserName.getText();
        return n;
    }
}
```

and this is my another Jpanel code for get user name and want to set it to jLabel.and i have called this method name in costructer.

```
public void setNameToInvoice(){
           Login l = new Login();
           String n = l.getUserName();
           lblCustomerName.setText(n);
}
```

Can some one please help me to do this?

Comment: Is `txtUserName.getText()` getting you anything in a debugger at that point?

Comment: Post the entire code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that when you're calling your `Login` class it displays a window prompting the user to input some information, but when you use it, the `Login#getUserName` is not returning what you expect?

This would be because `JFrame` is none-blocking, that is, once you make the frame visible, the code will continue executing what ever was left in your method.  This is the nature of event driven programming.

Instead of using a `JFrame`, you could use a modal dialog, which, when made visible, will block your code execution at the point it was made visible, until the dialog is closed.  After which you could then query the dialog for the information you need

Have a look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details